# vectorize list comprehension with non universal function

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, optimization, vectorization

I am attempting to maturely optimize something akin to this mwe code. I'm using a list comprehension but believe I should be able to vectorize it somehow.

```
A = numpy.arange(20000)
B = numpy.arange(20000, 50000)
C = [bin(i^j).count('1') for i in A for j in B].count(1)
```

(This is a search for all members in group `A` that are hamming distance 1 from a member in group `B`.) The sizes are of the correct order of magnitude, but I'll repeat the entire sequence about 100 times. The average size of `C` is expected to be around 10k.

I've been unsuccessful in creating a universal function `uhamming` for `bin(i^j).count('1')` with `numpy.frompyfunc`; I'm getting

```
module 'numpy' has no attribute 'uhamming'
```

I'd be quite happy to have `C` be an array. Thanks for looking!

FYI, here's my profiling output for a minimized version using (2000) and (2000, 5000):

```
     12000007 function calls in 5.442 seconds

Ordered by: internal time

ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
    1    2.528    2.528    5.342    5.342 <string>:4(<listcomp>)
6000000    1.527    0.000    1.527    0.000 {method 'count' of 'str' objects}
6000000    1.287    0.000    1.287    0.000 {built-in method builtins.bin}
    1    0.089    0.089    0.089    0.089 {method 'count' of 'list' objects}
    1    0.011    0.011    5.442    5.442 <string>:2(<module>)
    1    0.000    0.000    5.442    5.442 {built-in method builtins.exec}
    2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method numpy.core.multiarray.arange}
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
```

Comment: If an element of A is a hamming distance of 1 from multiple elements of B, should that count once, or multiple times?

Comment: Good question! Multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error suggests that someplace  you are using

```
numpy.unhamming
```

A quick and dirty use of `frompyfunc` would be:

```
In [126]: def unhamming(i,j):
     ...:     return bin(i^j).count('1')
     ...: 
In [127]: f = np.frompyfunc(unhamming, 2,1)
```

The function takes 2 inputs, and returns 1.

With smaller arrays:

```
In [124]: A = np.arange(200)
In [125]: B = np.arange(200,500)
In [128]: C = [bin(i^j).count('1') for i in A for j in B].count(1)
In [131]: C
Out[131]: 336
```

Using the 'vectorized' function:

```
In [129]: f(A,B[:,None])
Out[129]: 
array([[3, 4, 4, ..., 3, 3, 4],
       [4, 3, 5, ..., 2, 4, 3],
       [4, 5, 3, ..., 4, 2, 3],
       ..., 
       [6, 5, 7, ..., 4, 6, 5],
       [6, 7, 5, ..., 6, 4, 5],
       [7, 6, 6, ..., 5, 5, 4]], dtype=object)
```

And to find out how many 1's there are either turn it into a list, or use a numpy sum.

```
In [130]: _.ravel().tolist().count(1)
Out[130]: 336
In [132]: (f(A,B[:,None])==1).sum()
Out[132]: 336
```

Speed is basically the same

```
In [133]: timeit C = [bin(i^j).count('1') for i in A for j in B].count(1)
45 ms ± 380 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
In [134]: timeit (f(A,B[:,None])==1).sum()
46.1 ms ± 97.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Sometimes `frompyfunc` gives up to a 2x speed improvement over direct iteration.  But it still has to call your `unhamming` function many times.  It is not true 'vectorization' (in the sense of moving calculations to C level code).

I suspect there's a way of doing the same calculation with numpy expressions, broadcasting `A` against `B[:,None]`.  But I'll leave that to another time  or poster.

---

```
C = A ^ B[:,None]
```

does part of your function.  But I haven't found a version of `bin` that works on arrays (`np.binary_repr` doesn't help).

```
In [160]: f1 = np.frompyfunc(lambda x: bin(x).count('1'),1,1)
In [161]: f1(A^B[:,None])
Out[161]: 
array([[3, 4, 4, ..., 3, 3, 4],
       [4, 3, 5, ..., 2, 4, 3],
       [4, 5, 3, ..., 4, 2, 3],
       ..., 
       [6, 5, 7, ..., 4, 6, 5],
       [6, 7, 5, ..., 6, 4, 5],
       [7, 6, 6, ..., 5, 5, 4]], dtype=object)
In [162]: (f1(A^B[:,None])==1).sum()
Out[162]: 336
In [163]: timeit (f1(A^B[:,None])==1).sum()
37 ms ± 295 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Just a small improvement.

---

Searching on [numpy] and hamming produced this question: [Fastest way to get hamming distance for integer array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40875282/fastest-way-to-get-hamming-distance-for-integer-array)

Here's an adaptation of one of @Divaker's answers:

```
def foo(A, B):
    x = np.bitwise_xor(A,B[:,None])
    r = (1 << np.arange(15))[:,None]
    xr = (r[:,None]&x)
    xrc = (xr>0).sum(axis=0)
    return (xrc==1).sum()
In [280]: foo(A,B)
Out[280]: 336
```

It could be tweaked, for example adjust the size of `r`, changing the broadcasting and reshapes.  But the final sum matches.

Comment: Thanks @hpaulj, I figured the function calls would add some overhead and I'll play with this for larger numbers. And yes, I was using `numpy.uhamming.outer(A, B)`. What does `frompyfunc` do if not turn my function into a universal I could then use for broadcasting?

Comment: It doesn't turn it into a `ufunc` (with methods like `outer` and `reduce`).  But it does broadcast the inputs arrays, as shown in `In[32]`, same as `A*B[:,None]` or `np.add(A, B[:,None])`.

Comment: Thanks again @hpaulj. I’m still surprised the list comps aren’t much less efficient. Concurrent_futures?

Comment: Numba on the hamming function helps a bit . . .

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40875282/fastest-way-to-get-hamming-distance-for-integer-array might help.

Comment: This is all great stuff. List comprehension still wins out at larger values, ie: `A = numpy.arange(5000)
B = numpy.arange(5000,15000)` This suggests I may need to code this algorithm in C. It's ultimately 20 * (2 ** 20) hamming distance calculations, and I can't get this to complete on my machine without a kernel crash.