# Python: scipy/numpy all pairs computation between two 1-D vectors

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, hamming-distance, scipy-spatial

I have two lists `l1` and `l2` containing integers that may be of different lengths, and I want to perform a computation between every possible pairing between these two vectors.

Specifically, I'm checking the Hamming distance between each pair and if the distance is sufficiently small I want to "count" it.

Naively, this could be implemented

```
def hamming_distance(n1: int, n2: int) -> float:
    return bin(n1 ^ n2).count('1')/32.0

matches = 0

for n1 in l1:
    for n2 in l2:
        sim = 1 - hamming_distance(n1, n2)

        if sim >= threshold:
            matches += 1
```

But this is not very fast.

I've unsuccessfully tried to leverage `scipy.spatial.distance.cdist`, where I figured that I would first compute the Hamming distance between all pairs, as the [scipy.spatial.cdist documentation states](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html) that it will

> Compute distance between each pair of the two collections of inputs.

and then count the number of elements satisfying the predicate that `1 - d >= threshold` where `d` is the Hamming distance, i.e.

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist

l1 = l1.reshape(-1, 2)  # After np.array
l2 = l2.reshape(-1, 2)
r = cdist(l1, l2, 'hamming')
matches = np.count_nonzero(1 - r >= threshold)
```

but the number of matches found by the respective solutions are different. I've noticed that it is possible to call `cdist` with a function, `cdist(XA, XB, f)` but I have not succeeded in writing my implementation of `hamming_distance` so that it broadcasts properly.

I've looked at [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40875282/fastest-way-to-get-hamming-distance-for-integer-array) but it presumes that both lists are of the same length which is not the case here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are three approaches using

1. `scipy.spatial.KDTree`
2. `scipy.spatial.distance.cdist`
3. a lookup table

On a pair of 32bit int vectors of lengths 100 and 200 they all give the same result; speedwise they compare as follows:

```
count_sim_kd 16.408800622448325 ms
count_sim_cd 12.41896384395659 ms
count_sim_lu 0.8755046688020229 ms
```

So at this problem size look up wins by a huge margin.

Code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial import cKDTree as KDTree
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist

l1 = np.random.randint(0,2**32,100)
l2 = np.random.randint(0,2**32,200)
threshold = 10/32

def hamming_distance(n1: int, n2: int) -> float:
    return bin(n1 ^ n2).count('1')/32.0

matches = 0

for n1 in l1:
    for n2 in l2:
        sim = 1 - hamming_distance(n1, n2)

        if sim >= threshold:
            matches += 1

def count_sim_kd(a,b,th):
    A,B = (KDTree(np.unpackbits(x[:,None].view(np.uint8),axis=1))
           for x in (a,b))
    return A.sparse_distance_matrix(B,max_distance=32-int(32*th),p=1).nnz

def count_sim_cd(a,b,th):
    A,B = (np.unpackbits(x[:,None].view(np.uint8),axis=1) for x in (a,b))
    return np.count_nonzero(cdist(A,B,"minkowski",p=1)<=32-int(32*th))


lu = sum(np.unravel_index(np.arange(256),8*(2,)))
def count_sim_lu(a,b,th):
    return np.count_nonzero(lu[(a[:,None,None]^b[None,:,None])
                               .view(np.uint8)].sum(2)<=32-int(32*th))

from timeit import timeit
for f in (count_sim_kd,count_sim_cd,count_sim_lu):
    assert f(l1,l2,threshold)==matches
    print(f.__name__,timeit(lambda:f(l1,l2,threshold),number=100)*10,'ms')
```

Comment: I'm starting to have memory issues. 

    .view(np.uint8)].sum(2) <= 32 - int(32*th))
MemoryError: Unable to allocate 14.3 GiB for an array with shape (15488, 15488, 8) and data type int64

Would you recommend splicing `a` and `b` into halves? Or some other approach. Don't understand why numpy treats this as a int64 array.

Comment: @FilipAllberg It's because the lu table uses `int64`. Could you pls check whether `lu = sum(map(np.uint8,np.unravel_index(np.arange(256),8*(2,))))` solves your problem?

Comment: It did! I was just adding print(array.dtype) statements everywhere trying to figure this out! No out of memory error. Life-saver you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `np.bitwise_xor.outer` together with `np.binary_repr` and `np.char.count`:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=5)
b = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=5)

binary_repr = np.vectorize(np.binary_repr)
distance = np.char.count(binary_repr(np.bitwise_xor.outer(a, b)), '1') / 32
```

Then to get the matches:

```
matches = np.sum(distance >= threshold)
```

Comment: While this has feature parity, it wasn't significantly faster. The accepted answer resulted in a speed-up of about 100x in my use-case.