# numpy bitwise_and unable to broadcast argument 1 to output array

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization, hamming-distance

I'm trying to implement vectorization for answer from this question

[Fastest way to get hamming distance for integer array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40875282/fastest-way-to-get-hamming-distance-for-integer-array)

```
r = (1 << np.arange(64, dtype=np.uint64))[:, None]
def hamming_distance_v2(a, b):
    t = np.bitwise_xor(a, b)
    p = np.bitwise_and(t, r)
    return np.count_nonzero(p != 0)
```

I want to pass an 2d array as first parameter, for example

```
a = [[127,255], [127,255]]
b = [127,240]
hamming_distance_v1(a, b) -> [4,4]
```

If 2d array as first argument is used, the following error is returned:

```
ValueError: unable to broadcast argument 1 to output array
```

Is there a way to implement vectorization on current realization of hamming distance or some other ways to count this distance between 2d and 1d arrays?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the Q&A link's answer, they would modify to incorporate the extra dim as shown next.

**Approach #1**

```
def hamming_distance(a, b):
    r = (1 << np.arange(8))[:,None]
    mask = (a[:,None] & r) != (b & r)
    return mask.sum((1,2))
```

**Approach #2**

```
def hamming_distance_v2(a, b):
    r = (1 << np.arange(8))[:,None]
    xor = np.bitwise_xor(a[:,None],b)
    mask = (xor & r) != 0
    return mask.sum((1,2))
```

**Approach #3**

Another with [`np.unpackbits`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unpackbits.html) -

```
def hamming_distance_v3(a, b):
    a = np.asarray(a, dtype=np.uint8)
    b = np.asarray(b, dtype=np.uint8)
    m = np.unpackbits(a,axis=1) != np.unpackbits(b)
    return m.sum(1)
```

Sample run -

```
In [107]: a
Out[107]: 
array([[127, 255],
       [127, 205],
       [227, 255]])

In [108]: b
Out[108]: array([127, 240])

In [109]: hamming_distance(a, b)
Out[109]: array([4, 5, 8])
```

Comment: For looping over the a array and using non-vectorized is faster then using those vectorized functions, could it be a problem with length of a array?

Comment: @AlexanderKarp Faster than all of the posted three approaches?

Comment: faster then hamming_distance and hamming_distance_v2, hamming_distance_v3 I can't use cause np.unpackbits can't be used with uint64
https://pastebin.com/S3rDJmr3 I got best result with step = 1 (27s), if step is length of slided array computation get stuck

Comment: @AlexanderKarp Can you share the loop version?

Comment: Some clarification: I have a source array and a target array and I want to find the place in source array where hamming distance with target array is minimum possible.

So there are two approach to do it: for looping with step=1 and sliding source array to windows to implement vectorization, there are both of them: https://pastebin.com/fF9K6X1z

Comment: Loop version with numba  on array **a** with shape  (2095250,) and array **b** (250,)  runs for 20 seconds, vectorized version with windowed array **a** (2095001, 250) and **b** (250,) was killed by my OS with exit code 137 :)